# Android: Execute code when app is "activated", not on orientation change

Tags: android, android-orientation, activity-lifecycle

in my application (`minSdkVersion` 17, but I am flexible concerning this), I have a single activity. It displays some kind of timetable. I want to let it show the current day and scroll to the correct time.
This functionality is already working perfectly fine.

I want to do this everytime when the app is started, or everytime when the app becomes active again (e.g. after pressing the home button and just clicking the app icon again without killing the app inbetween).

But I do NOT want to do this, when the device is rotated.

For example, I have a method:

```
private void scrollToNow() {
    // do the calculation and scroll all views to the correct position
    // this is code I already have fully functional!
}
```

And I want to execute it every time the activity gets active again, but NOT on orientation change.

I tried a lot of combinations (in `onStart`, `onResume`, `onCreate`), but none of them did the trick. I tried to build a solution using the savedInstanceState but failed.

Anybody got some tips or useful links for me?

Thanks alot,

Oliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, think twice before you decide to check configuration changes manually.

> If your application doesn't need to update resources during a specific configuration change and you have a performance limitation that requires you to avoid the activity restart, then you can declare that your activity handles the configuration change itself, which prevents the system from restarting your activity.
>
> Note: Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much more difficult to use alternative resources, because the system does not automatically apply them for you. This technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and is not recommended for most applications.

Try to save some flag in `onSaveInstanceState` and in onCreate check if there is savedInstanceState, then save it as field for example. This will give you information about does activity is 'recreated' or not. Then in 'onResume' check is this flag set or not. If not, then you are not 'recreated' your activity, so you can invoke `scrollToNow()`

Comment: I think I tried that already, but in that case, if I remember correctly, I even got that flag when the activity was destroyed for some other reason besides orientation change. I will try it again. Thank you!

Comment: ok, i tested it again, and onCreate is called with a Bundle instance only and only if the orientation changes. I tested the following cases: new app start, pressing the home button, going back to the app with/without killing it. So I think I did some mistake when I tried it. I think I forgot to reset the flag once onResume was executed.

Answer (score 1):

> I dont want to recreate layout when screen orientation change

Did you tried to add this line to your `AndroidManifest.xml` `android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"` like that :

```
<activity
        android:name="youractivity"
        android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create_note"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

For more information you can take a look at : [manifest/activity-element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) in that page go to **android:configChanges** section and read please .

When adding this you must handle  `onConfigurationChanged()`  method by yourself instead of Android System.

Please read carefully Note section in that page :

> Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last resort. Please read [Handling Runtime Changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.

Also i am using this in my application maybe you can try this too : `android:screenOrientation="nosensor"` in that page you can find information about it too.

Comment: I think at one point I tried using `android:configChanges`, but as I remember, it only contained two of the values (perhaps for an older sdk version?). With all three, it works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: @OliverMeyer i think orientation attribute was missing , because you facing that problem (?) when your phones orientation changed. Also added another way which i am using in my application maybe you can try it too.